# run scripts in protected sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to run a script on a group of spreadsheets in a group drive folder. these workbooks are protected and I currently do not have permissions to edit in those protections( i do have edit permissions on the sheet though ).

I know that you can't run scripts on protected spreadsheets, and asking the owners of the sheets to give me permission to edit those sheets  one by one would take forever.

I thought I could make a script  to insert myself as editor on the protected sheets to be able to run the script on those workbooks. but did not work either

this is what i am trying to do :

```
function addEditAccess_(sheet) {

  var protections = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET);
  for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
    protections[i].addEditor('my email.');
  }

}
```

this function receives a sheet as a parameter and im calling this in this code snippet:

```
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    const file = files.next();
    const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(file);
     
    const sheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();
     sheets.forEach(sheet => {
    addEditAccess_(sheet);

//rest of the code
```

this is the error it throws :
*Exception: You do not have permission to perform that action.*

i tried to change  `SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET` to `SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE`
and also tried using `remove()` . (in testing sheets , no worries). None worked.

I would like to know if it is possible to do this or not.  should i search for an alternative solution?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your current situation. In order to correctly understand it, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current issue? First, I would like to correctly understand your current situation.

Comment: Just to be clear... you want to run a script but you don't have "edit" permission. You wonder whether you could edit a script so as to grant yourself permission. From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#access_to_bound_scripts): `All container-bound scripts use the same owner, viewer, and editor access list defined for the container file. The container owner takes ownership of a new script project regardless of who created it.` Short of logging as in the owner, your "edit" permissions are tracked in the Project editor, and your idea won't work.

Comment: Hello @Tanaike ,in short,, I was trying to see if I could progamatically add myself as an editor of protected spreadsheets that were in a folder. Those spreadsheets were already protected before they were shared with me and although they shared the folder with me as an editor, I can't edit values or run scripts in those files because I am restricted from modifying because of the protections.

Comment: But as @Tedinoz mentions, I probably can't do what I was trying to do. the only thing I can think of is to make copies of those sheets, since I think the protections will now go to me, or have the owner run a script to insert me as editor of the protected sheets.

Comment: now im curious, if the spreadsheet is protected with warnings  only, can i run scripts that modify values in the sheets?

Comment: `have the owner run a script to insert me as editor of the protected sheets`. Now, that is worth thinking about.